# memmove not copying all the content of buffer - C

Tags: c, malloc, buffer, printf, memmove

I have the following code in which I'm trying to create a buffer of length 7 bytes and then put an integer in network byte order along with a char array in the buffer, I should not have the Null character at the end of my `sprintf()` buffer so I'm using `memcpy()` to just copy 7 bytes. However, I seem to be getting different buffers after `memcpy()`.

Code:

```
int num = 1234;
char *dummy = "bla";
int dummy_len = strlen(dummy);
int buffer_len = sizeof(int) + dummy_len;
char *buffer = malloc(buffer_len);
char *temp_buf = malloc(buffer_len);
size_t len = buffer_len;

sprintf(temp_buf, "%d%s",htonl(num),dummy); //preparing the temp_buf
memmove(buffer, temp_buf, len); 
printf("sizeof(temp_buf) = %d and sizeof(buffer) = %d\n",sizeof(temp_buf), sizeof(buffer));
printf("printing buffer = %s and temp_buf = %s\n", buffer,temp_buf);
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
sizeof(temp_buf) = 4 and sizeof(buffer) = 4
printing buffer = -771489 and temp_buf = -771489792bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the sprintf, just copy the data directly.

```
int temp = htonl(num);
memmove(buffer, &temp, sizeof(temp));
memmove(buffer+sizeof(temp), dummy, strlen(dummy));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is incoherent to use `sizeof(int)` and then `sprintf(...,"%d...` Not all 4-byte integers print with 4 digits in decimal.

In particular, `htonl(num)` is likely not to print with a 4-digit decimal representation. Therefore, `sprintf()` overflows the buffer `temp_buf`.

You should use something like:

```
uint32_t n = htonl(num);
memcpy(temp_buf, &n, sizeof(n));
```

Comment: Yes I just used len = 13 and the buffer content are the same. Okay is there an alternative way by which I can convert my int to network byte order while retaining its size of 4 bytes?

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar If you are not trying to obtain a printable string, then `memcpy()` should work fine. If you need to obtain a printable string or limit yourself to decimal digits for some reason, then it is impossible, by a counting argument, to represent integers that range from -2^31 to 2^31-1 in a string that ranges from 0000 to 9999.

Comment: Yes your suggestions is correct and so is the suggestion by @Chris Olsen. This added to my knowledge!